# jQuery "floating bubble" effect on scroll - optimization?

Tags: jquery

I made a floating bubble via jQuery that scrolls a bit faster than the user:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3q74.jpg

This is the code:

```
if ($('#bubble').isInViewport()){

    var where = ($('#bubble').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) / $(window).height();
    var multiplyBy = 180;
    if ($(window).height() > $(window).width()){
        // if portrait, don't move that fast
        multiplyBy = 150;
    }
    if ($(window).height() < 800){
        // if mobile, don't move that fast
        multiplyBy = 110;
    }
    var topVal = (where * multiplyBy)

    $("#bubble").css("top", (topVal + "px"));
}
```

But this way it's a bit laggy.

Is there a better method to achieve this effect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about working code, that are asking for help on improving said code, are off topic for Stack Overflow and belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could look into parallax scrolling, there are some methods to get this effect going with plain css (z-index and perspective), see https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/ for an example.